# Dual Monitor problems

Tags: nvidia, 16.04, multiple-monitors

Good Afternoon,

I'm running Kubuntu 16.04, and on a Laptop with Nvidia Graphics, and a use an external display. The first time I connected the monitor, everything worked exactly as I wanted, and by extension, expected.

Yesterday, I needed to take my PC to class, and I therefore removed the display. When I got back, it didn't work anymore(the display said no signal).

What I have tried thus far : 
I resetted the xorg.conf file,
I completely reinstalled KDE,
and I created a new user( this gave me back the use of my display, but this is not an ideal solution).

Please advise on how to completely reset my user account in term of displays etc.

Also, I'm happy to run additional troubleshooting, but since I'm new to Linux in general, I wouldn't know the appropriate commands.

Kind regards,
wpswart

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "didn't work anymore"?

Comment: I plugged it into my HDMI port and it didn't receive a signal.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add the information. What possibly works is deleting your `~/.config/monitors.xml` file, immediately log out and back in. Please mention if it helps.

Comment: There is no such file in that directory, or anywhere else. I think Nvidia X Server handles this.

Comment: Does your monitor have the option to select inputs?